# Исчезла ссылка на перенесённый вопрос

Tags: дефект, перенос-вопросов

В [перенесённом вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6816/178988?noredirect=1) показывается плашка

> Вопрос размещён на сайте для программистов.

Хотя должно быть сообщение о переносе на основной сайт со ссылкой на вопрос.

А ещё ссылка с главной страницы не редиректится.

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: @Alex78191, ты вот тут смотришь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/777786/178988, впрочем, у меня там тоже ссылок нет.

Comment: *«... был размещён на **форуме** обсуждений...»* — так мы форум или база знаний? А может, просто *«сайт» (для программистов)*?